# Buttons should Inherit parent div width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set 3 buttons on bottom of product box like image on left side also they should be responsive but couldn't do it:

[image: To do]

Following is HTML & CSS where buttons are not inheriting the parent div width:

```css
.pro-box{
 height: 416px;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 padding: 6px 6px 0 6px;
 background-color: #4dbaef;
 color: #fff;
}
.pro-box>img{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 242px;
}
.btn-pro{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 letter-spacing: 1px;
 font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 background-color: #339dd1;
 border-radius: 0;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 12px;
 margin-right: 2px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}
.pro-box>.btn-group{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 20px;
 left: 20px;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-3">
<div class="pro-box">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <h4 class="pro-name">MAQ03422</h4>
  <p class="pro-desc">Titanium Delicate Touch Microvascular Needle Holders Needle Holders and Passers</p>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pro">Tray</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pro">cart</a>
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pro">compare</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Who can modify your code image?

Comment: Instead of posting images of code, post the actual code please

Comment: Is it appropriate now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use flex by adding `display:flex` to container and then set `flex:1` to buttons. You need to also set `position:relative` on the main container since you are using `position:absolute`.

```css
.pro-box {
  height: 416px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding: 6px 6px 0 6px;
  background-color: #4dbaef;
  color: #fff;
  position:relative;
}

.pro-box>img {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 242px;
}

.btn-pro {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Roboto Regular', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #339dd1;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.pro-box>.btn-group {
  position: absolute;
  display:flex;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.pro-box>.btn-group > .btn {
  flex:1;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-lg-3">
  <div class="pro-box">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="" class="img-responsive">
    <h4 class="pro-name">MAQ03422</h4>
    <p class="pro-desc">Titanium Delicate Touch Microvascular Needle Holders Needle Holders and Passers</p>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-pro">Tray</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-pro">cart</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-pro">compare</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u so much for your help :-)